# Re-ordering entries in a model using drag-and-drop

Tags: javascript, python, django

Say I have a blogging app in Django. How can i re-order the posts using a draggable table in the default admin?

It would be best if i didn't have to add any extra fields to the model, but if i really have to i can.

Comment: What's the best solution now, for django 1.2/1.3 in 2011?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For working code to do this, check out [snippet 1053](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1053/) at [djangosnippets.org](http://www.djangosnippets.org).

Answer (score 4):

Note on the "It would be best if i didn't have to add any extra fields to the model, but if i really have to i can."

Sorry, but order of information in a database is determined by the information itself:  you always have to add a column for ordering.  There's really no choice about that.

Further, to retrieve things in this order, you'll need to specifically add `.order_by(x)` to your queries or add `ordering` to your model.

```
class InOrder( models.Model ):
    position = models.IntegerField()
    data = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = [ 'position' ]
```

Without the additional field ordering cannot happen.  It's one of the rules of relational databases.

Comment: Thanks, contrary to the author I was looking for the line to add !

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice package for ordering admin objects these days

https://github.com/iambrandontaylor/django-admin-sortable

Also, [django-suit](http://djangosuit.com/) has builtin support for this

Comment: Unfortunately django-suit's implementation isn't drag-and-drop.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this snippet https://gist.github.com/barseghyanartur/1ebf927512b18dc2e5be (originally based on this snippet http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2160/).

Integration is very simple.

Your model (in models.py):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    # Other fields...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order',)
```

You admin (admin.py):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name', 'order',) # Add other fields here
    list_display = ('name', 'order',)
    list_editable = ('order',)

    class Media:
        js = (
            '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js',
            '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.js',
            'path/to/sortable_list.js',
        )
```

Change the JS (of the snippet) accordingly if your attributes responsible for holding the name and ordering are named differently in your model.

Answer (score 1):

In model class you would probably have to add "order" field, to maintain specific order (eg. item with order = 10 is the last one and order = 1 is the first one). Then you can add a JS code in admin change_list template (see [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions)) to maintain drag&drop feature. Finally change ordering in Meta of model to something like ['order'].

Answer (score 0):

The order can only be determined if you add a field in your model.Let's add a position field in your model.

```
In your models.py 

class MainModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('position',)

In your apps admin.py

class IdeaCardTagInline(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = MainModel
    extra = 0
    min_num = 1
    sortable_field_name = "position"
```

`ordering = ('position',)` in Meta will order the MainModel according to the value in the position field. 
`sortable_field_name = "position"` will help in autofill of the value in position when an user drag and drop the multiple models.

To see the same order in your api, use order_by(x) in views_model.py.
Just a model example:

```
Model.objects.filter().order_by('position').
```