# Drag and drop ordering of formset with extra entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have been looking for a way to allow the user to easily change the order of entries in a formset.  I found [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110774/re-ordering-entries-in-a-model-using-drag-and-drop) that addresses this subject, with the accepted answer referencing a [Django Snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1053/) that uses a JQuery tool to allow drag 'n drop of the entries.  This is nifty and cool, but I have a problem with 'extra' entries.  If an 'extra' entry is modified and then dragged I get an error on the submit:

`(1048, "Column 'order' cannot be null")`

I believe Django keeps the 'extra' entries separate, since they have to be inserted instead of updates.  So the reordering probably confuses matters.  Is there a way to make this work, or are there other suggestions for reordering and/or adding new entries?

Edit: Added some relevant code excerpts.  I'm trying this out in the admin, as the snippet shows.  I'd like to put it in my own page ultimately, however.

models.py:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    section_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    section_name = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    score_order = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.section_name
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'section'
        ordering = [u"score_order"]

class Chair(models.Model):
    chair_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, null=True, blank=True,
      limit_choices_to={'current_member': True})
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=135)
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
      return "%s - %s" % (self.description, self.member)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'chair'
        ordering = (u'section', u'order')
```

admin.py

```
class SectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Section
    class Media:
        js = (
            '/scripts/jquery.js',
            '/scripts/ui.core.js',
            '/scripts/ui.sortable.js',
            '/scripts/section-sort.js',
        )

class ChairInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Chair

admin.site.register(Section,
                    inlines = [ChairInline],
                    form = SectionForm,
)
```

Comment: Could you post your model and any custom form code to give a better context?

Comment: Also, any relevant JS that isn't in the linked snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my own solution.  The snippet was setting the order for every row that had a non-empty primary key value.  But the extra rows have an empty primary key, and I believe they have to stay empty for Django to know that they are to be inserted instead of updated.  I modified the function to check for the other fields being empty (fortunately, I only have a couple) as well as the primary key:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('div.inline-group').sortable({
        items: 'div.inline-related',
        handle: 'h3:first',
        update: function() {
            $(this).find('div.inline-related').each(function(i) {
                if ($(this).find('input[id$=chair_id]').val() ||
                  $(this).find('select[id$=member]').val() ||
                      $(this).find('select[id$=description]').val()) {
                    $(this).find('input[id$=order]').val(i+1);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('div.inline-related h3').css('cursor', 'move');
    $('div.inline-related').find('input[id$=order]').parent('div').hide();
});
```

This did the trick for me.  I could maybe improve it by adding a hidden field to the form that gets set whenever any field on a row gets modified.  But at this point I'm still a jQuery n00b, so this will do.  If anybody has better ideas, feel free to comment or add another answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do sortable formsets in one of my apps. I use this jQuery drag and drop plugin:

http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

I bind the plugin's onDrop event to a function that resets the value of all "order" fields.

Additionally, I pass initial data to the formset so the formset's extra "order" fields always have a value in cases where there is no javascript available - the user won't be able to re-order rows, but they can edit and post changes without the null error you described.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've found my own solution, which I'll post as an answer shortly.  This plugin sounds similar to the jQuery UI plugin I'm using.  I can't use initial values since I'm using an [inline formset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442040/pre-populate-an-inline-formset), and I don't think that would help.  It would avoid the error, but the modified extra rows still wouldn't get the correct order.  I dunno, if you have this working you must have solved this.